# OVS : How to calculate ICMPV6 checksum?

Tags: network-programming, ipv6, checksum, icmp, openvswitch

Have been working on simulating "Router Advertisement" in OVS for certain requests, for that I constructed a ICMPv6 pkt with all the fields correct except the checksum, wireshark gives an error on the checksum part.

ICMP6 checksum should include `src + dst + icmp_length + next_header`
but following code is calculating incorrectly. 
Am I missing something ? appreciate the help guys.

```
struct nd_router_advert *ra; 
struct ofpbuf *ra_rsp;
struct ovs_16aligned_ip6_hdr *nh;
.
.
.
.
.
ofpbuf_set_l3(ra_rsp, nh);
nh->ip6_vfc = 0x60;
nh->ip6_plen = htons(sizeof(*ra));
nh->ip6_nxt = IPPROTO_ICMPV6;
.
.
ofpbuf_set_l4(ra_rsp, ra);
ra->nd_ra_type = ND_ROUTER_ADVERT;
ra->nd_ra_code = 0; 
ra->nd_ra_cksum = htons(0);
ra->nd_ra_curhoplimit = 255; 
ra->nd_ra_flags_reserved = 0; 
ra->nd_ra_router_lifetime = htons(9000);
ra->nd_ra_reachable = htons(0);
ra->nd_ra_retransmit = htons(0);

packet_set_ipv6(ra_rsp, IPPROTO_ICMPV6, src, dst, 0, 0, 212);
ra->nd_ra_cksum = recalc_csum16(ra->nd_ra_cksum, 0, htons(sizeof(*ra)));
ra->nd_ra_cksum = recalc_csum32(ra->nd_ra_cksum, 0, IPPROTO_ICMPV6);
```

Answer (score 1):

The ICMPv6 checksum is calculated over the the sum of the entire ICMPv6 message. The definition of how to calculate the checksum is in [RFC 4441, ICMPv6 (ICMP for IPv6), Section 2.3, Message Checksum Calculation](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4443#section-2.3):

> **2.3.  Message Checksum Calculation**
>
> The checksum is the 16-bit one's complement of the one's complement
> sum of the entire ICMPv6 message, starting with the ICMPv6 message
> type field, and prepended with a "pseudo-header" of IPv6 header
> fields, as specified in [IPv6, Section 8.1].  The Next Header value
> used in the pseudo-header is 58.  (The inclusion of a pseudo-header in
> the ICMPv6 checksum is a change from IPv4; see [IPv6] for the
> rationale for this change.)
>
> For computing the checksum, the checksum field is first set to zero.